# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql. SQLState: 08001. VendorError: 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, tomcat9

I know here are lot of questions here on this topic. I tried all solutions but still can't get connection to data base. Please help!
I am working on web app. NetBeans, Tomcat 9, MySQL.

**Error:**

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306user=webstudent&password=webstudent
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "con" is null
```

**My files in project:**

Context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/LibraryWebApp"/>
```

DB.java:

```
package dao;
import java.sql.*;

//Database connection method
public class DB {
    public static Connection getCon() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection con=null;
    try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"+
                                   "user=webstudent&password=webstudent");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
    } catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    return con;
}     
}
```

[See imported libraries in the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkgLz.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306user=webstudent&password=webstudent

Your connection string is incorrect. You've missed the database name. So, update the database name in the following string and use it.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?user=webstudent&password=webstudent
```

Also, place the following statement prior to connection stmt

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

**Updated:**

Add the `serverTimezone` explicitly in the connection string
Eg:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?user=webstudent&password=webstudent&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the database name "library" so now my string is:
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?user=webstudent&password=webstudent`

But nothing changed and I still have the same errors.

Comment: updated answer, plz check.

Comment: I think it helped since error  `No suitable driver found` disappeared but error `Cannot invoke` still there + new one: `SQLException: The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
SQLState: 01S00
VendorError: 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "con" is null
`.

Comment: Add the `serverTimezone explicitly` in the connection string. Updated

Comment: Fantastic! It works now. Thanks a lot!